# In Android Studio, with what mechanism can I listen to data generated in a Service from an Activity?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

I am working in Android Studio, in Kotlin, I have a service that will run in the foreground, that is with a fixed notification to the user, the idea is that the service will generate certain values from time to time and emit them, I am looking for some mechanism that by opening any Activity, said Activity can subscribe to the data published by the Service, I was thinking of using a BroadCast Receiver, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach, thank you very much in advance.

I was thinking of using a BroadCast Receiver, but I'm not sure if it's the best approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Datastore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) or Room to store the values and collect them wherever you want using flow